# Sort multiple relative Lists in Java

Tags: java, android, dictionary, arraylist, comparator

I have seen other similar questions - but people are unable to understand those questions well to give good solutions - so ill try to do better...

I have two lists, one for Events names and one for events times

```
List<String> eventNames= new ArrayList<String>();
List<Calendar> eventTimes= new ArrayList<Calendar>();
```

There is a 1 to 1 relation between these lists, so the first item in eventNames is related to the first item of eventTimes...and same for the second items, the third...etc..

I can use the following to order eventTimes in ascending order:

```
Collections.sort(eventTimes, new Comparator<Calendar>() {
    public int compare(Calendar c1, Calendar c2) {
        return c1.getTime().compareTo(c2.getTime());
    }
});
```

but I want to sort both of these lists by the times of the events in eventTimes.

**I believe I need to 'Map' these lists...? but I don't understand how to do that?**

Comment: encapsulate both of them in an object, create a list of that object and then sort by date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to create a new entity `class` just to sort them, then you can create a list of integers representing the indices and sort that instead using a comparator with the list of `Calendar`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final List<String> eventNames= new ArrayList<String>();
    final List<Calendar> eventTimes= new ArrayList<Calendar>();
    ArrayList<Integer> indices = range(eventNames.size());
    Collections.sort(indices, new Comparator<Integer>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Integer i, Integer j) {
            return eventTimes.get(i).compareTo(eventTimes.get(j));
        }
    });

    //Now to get the index i = 5 after sort you must do this
    eventNames.get(indices.get(5));
}

private static ArrayList<Integer> range(int size) {
    return range(0, size);
}

public static ArrayList<Integer> range(int start, int end) {
    ArrayList<Integer> list = Lists.newArrayList();
    for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {
        list.add(i);
    }
    return list;
}
```

PS: I am not proud of the piece of code above. To make some sense either wrap this code in a class or create a comparable entity class.

Comment: Thanks, This was the solution I chose to go ahead with although the other suggestions were also helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The [Apache Commons Math](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/) library has a utility method that allows you to do something similar for double[] arguments, see [MathArrays#sortInPlace(...)](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/javadocs/api-3.6.1/org/apache/commons/math3/util/MathArrays.html#sortInPlace(double[],%20double[]...)). It should be quite trivial to adjust the code for Collections and arbitrary types by using `compareTo(...)` instead of double comparison.

Answer (score 0):

Define a new class, for example:

```
public class Event {
    private final String name;
    private final Calendar time;

    public Event(String name, Calendar time) {
        this.name = name;
        this.time = time;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public Calendar getTime() {
        return time;
    }
}
```

and store the names and times of your events in a single `List` of `Event`'s.

Answer (score 0):

Create new entity class for and encapsulate both in that entity

```
        public class NewEntity {
         String eventNames;    
         Calendar eventTimes;
    // Getter and setter here 
    }
```

And then when you are adding them to collection.

```
List<NewEntity > newEntityList = new ArrayList<NewEntity >();

NewEntity newEntityFirst = new NewEntity();
newEntityFirst .setEventNames(eventNameFirst);
newEntityFirst .setEventTimes(eventTimesFirst);
newEntityList.add(newEntityFirst);


NewEntity newEntitySecond = new NewEntity();
newEntitySecond .setEventNames(eventNameSecond);
newEntitySecond .setEventTimes(eventTimesSecond);
newEntityList .add(newEntitySecond);
```

So you will get the related events and their names

Hope this will help :)